# How to map values and assign many values to "other" category?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
col1  col2
3     A
3     B
5     A
1     C
6     B
```

How can I replace 3 by 0 and 5 by 1, while the rest of numbers should be replaced by 2?

Expected result:

```
col3  col2
0     A
0     B
1     A
2     C
2     B
```

This is what I wrote so far:

```
vals = {3:0, 5:1}
df["col3"] = df["col1"].map(vals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `map` return missing values for non matched values, add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
vals = {3:0, 5:1}
df["col3"] = df["col1"].map(vals).fillna(2).astype(int)
print (df)
   col1 col2  col3
0     3    A     0
1     3    B     0
2     5    A     1
3     1    C     2
4     6    B     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You already close to what you need, just use `df.assign` to create a new column and replace `nan` values with `DataFrame.replace` and convert later to int.

```
>>> df.assign(col3=df["col1"].map(vals).replace(np.nan, 2).astype(int))
   col1 col2  col3
0     3    A     0
1     3    B     0
2     5    A     1
3     1    C     2
4     6    B     2
```

On the top of it as you are looking to have only `col2` and `col3` hence you can drop `col1` as follows ..

### Expected output:

```
>>> df.assign(col3=df["col1"].map(vals).replace(np.nan, 2).astype(int)).drop(columns={'col1'})
  # df = df.assign(col3=df["col1"].map(vals).replace(np.nan, 2).astype(int)).drop(columns={'col1'})
  col2  col3
0    A     0
1    B     0
2    A     1
3    C     2
4    B     2
```